# Corona SDK, OOP with display objects

Tags: lua, coronasdk, game-engine

I kinda understand the basics of OOP with lua using metatables.  but things get a little hairy when I am really intending to subclass a display object.  I don't believe I can pass the display object itself into the setmetatable function.  I'd really like to add extra functions to the display object directly.

for example.. here is my player.lua file

```
local player = {}
local player_mt = { __index = player }  -- metatable

function player.new( world )    -- constructor

    local obj = display.newRect( world, 0, 0, 20, 20 )
    obj:setFillColor( 1,0,0 )

    local tbl = { obj = obj }
    return setmetatable( tbl, player_mt )
end

function player:fillColor( r,g,b )
    self.obj:setFillColor( r,g,b )
end

function player:setPos( x,y )
    self.obj.x, self.obj.y = x,y
end

return player
```

this works out okay.. but I'd really like `self` to refer to my `obj` variable.  When I'm using this "class" I always have to reference the display object by saying `player.obj`.   I'd rather it was just `player`

any way of accomplishing this or better approaches?

just tried using my shape object directly and calling `fillColor` on my updated player object.  says it cant call `fillColor` on nil

```
local player = {}
local player_mt = { __index = player }  -- metatable

function player.new( world )    -- constructor

    local obj = display.newRect( world, 0, 0, 20, 20 )
    obj:setFillColor( 1,0,0 )

    return setmetatable( obj, player_mt )
end

function player:fillColor( r,g,b )
    self:setFillColor( r,g,b )
end

return player
```

Comment: Is `obj` a table? A userdata? Something else? You can forward every non-matching lookup from `tbl` to `obj` with your metatable if that's what you want.

Comment: obj is a display object.  https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/ShapeObject/index.html

Comment: Then yes you probably can't pass that to setmetatable. You can use __index (or __index chains) to allow for `ply:setFillColor(...)` to work though ensuring you get the right object passed to the right function with such a chain can be complicated.

Comment: " I don't believe I can pass the display object itself into the setmetatable function."  Have you tried?

Comment: Yes I tried.  When calling self on the display object within other methods I get errors.  Did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating like this,

```
local player= {}

function player.new(params)

  local self = {}
  setmetatable(self, {__index = player})

   local obj = display.newRect( world, 0, 0, 20, 20 )
   obj:setFillColor( 1,0,0 )

  self._obj  = obj  
  return self 
end


function player:fillColor( r,g,b )
  self._obj:setFillColor( r,g,b )
end

return player
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the best way ive found so far of extending the display object directly

```
local new
local sayName

sayName = function( self )
    print( self.name )
end

new = function( world )
    local player = display.newRect( world, 0, 0, 20, 20 )
    player:setFillColor( 1,0,0 )
    player.name = 'bob'

    player.sayName = sayName
    return player
end

local public = {}
public.new = new
return public
```